# Xorg stops working after all X applications has exited

Tags: linux, xorg, xserver

I have a simple application which I use to determinate when my X server is ready. The application is used in the init process, and all X-applications depend on it to be completed. It keeps on trying to connect, and when it does get a connection, it simply exits.

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Display *dis;

    while(1){
        dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

        if(dis != 0)
            break;
        usleep(1000);
    }

    if(dis != 0)
       XCloseDisplay(dis);

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is, that after I upgraded my Nvidia driver, none of the X-applications was able to display anything on the screen, if they ran after this simple test.

Also, if I run xeyes as the first application, then it works. Then if I press Ctrl-c ( to end the running xeyes application), and start a new one, nothing is displayed on the screen, but no errors appear on the screen.

Is this the expected behavioral? Is Xorg supposed to stop working after the last X-application has exited?

Comment: Have you checked the log file?

Answer (score 2):

X has the concept of "server generations": whenever the last clients disconnects from the X server, the server tries to reset itself and then we say it started a new "generation". Most users never get past the first generation, so multiple generations are not tested very much, so it is not a big surprise if you trigger a bug when using multiple generations. There are often memory leaks when new generations are triggered. If you find a bug triggered when the X server gets to new server generations, please report it to bugs.freedesktop.org.

From your environment description, it seems you're triggering new server generations. You can start X with "-noreset" to avoid having the server reset, possibly hiding any existing bugs (it is a good test!).

As a side note, you might consider replacing the program you pasted for a scheme using SIGUSR1. The following text is from "man Xserver":

> ```
>   SIGUSR1 This  signal  is  used  quite  differently from either of the above.
>           When the server starts, it checks to see if it has inherited
>           SIGUSR1 as SIG_IGN instead of the usual SIG_DFL.  In this case, the server
>           sends a SIGUSR1 to its parent process after it has  set
>           up the various connection schemes.  Xdm uses this feature to recognize
>           when connecting to the server is possible.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously not expected behaviour.

But the fact that you are using this 'polling' program indicates to me that you are trying to workaround other bugs.

There have been [known issues](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/615549) with fast-booting machines, Ubuntu+Nvidia+plymouth; See if you can upgrade your system or disable plymouth?

Also, can you check what `vty` X is running on when it 'stops working' ?

```
ps -ef | grep X
gdmtty="$(ps --no-heading -o tty -p $(pgrep X))"
stty -F "/dev/$gdmtty"
ps -f -t "$gdmtty"
```

(sometimes the terminal flags with regard to SIGNALS would be inapropriate for XServer and your Ctrl-C might cause the issue then).

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case here. I'm not using any official distribution, and the init process is developed internal. There is not installed plymouth on the target.